# Multiple consumer threads need to read the same element from a queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I have a requirement to where in multiple consumers need to read all the elements from a queue in python. I am using ThreadpoolExecutor to submit tasks. e.g if queue has 3 elements and there are 3 consumer threads, all 3 consumers need to get all the 3 elements from the queue. Problem with queue.get() is that it reads and pops the element out from the queue. I am using queue.queue[0] to get the top element and only pop the element when all the consumer threads has read the top element. Here is my demo code -

```
   def read():
       if (self.q.empty()) or (self.q.queue[0]==self.sentinel):
        raise Exception("Empty Queue")

       if (self not in self.read_ports):
        # Acquire lock
        self.condition.acquire()
        data = self.q.queue[0]
        self.read_ports.append(self)
        # Release lock
        self.condition.release()
            #print("Read ports1", self.read_ports)
    if self.is_identical(self.input_ports, self.read_ports):
        #print("Read ports2", self.read_ports)

        # All ports have read the top element, pop it now and clear read ports
        #Acquire lock
        self.q.get()
        self.read_ports.clear()
        # Release lock notify all waiting threads`
```

The Problem is that I need to notify the waiting threads when there is a new top element available. I am not sure how to use the threading.Condition object with ThreadpoolExecutor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Re, "Problem with queue.get() is that it reads and pops the element out from the queue." That's pretty much what _makes_ it a queue. IMO, the simplest solution* would be to have a separate queue for each consumer, and have the producer stuff each new item into all of the consumer queues. [\*When in doubt, try the simplest first, and only try something more elaborate if driven by need.]

Comment: Have you tried a publish-subscribe model where the producer publishes the values to multiple queues, each one uniquely accessed by a single consumer? This model will allow all consumer access to all values published.

Answer (score 0):

If N consumers need to get all the elements from a single source queue, then copy that value to N queues:

```py
from time import sleep
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


END = object()


def feed(queue: Queue):
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"Producing item {i}")
        sleep(0.5)
        queue.put(i)
    queue.put(END)


def dispatch(q_in: Queue, qs_out: list[Queue]):
    while True:
        item = q_in.get()
        
        if item is END:
            for q_out in qs_out:
                q_out.put(END)
            break
        
        for q_out in qs_out:
            q_out.put(item)


def process(item: int):
    sleep(0.5)
    print(f"Processed item {item}")


def worker(q_in: Queue):
    while True:
        item = q_in.get()
        if item is END: break
        process(item)


def main():
    q_in = Queue(maxsize=1)
    qs_out = [Queue(maxsize=1) for _ in range(3)]

    threads: list[Thread] = []
    
    threads.append(Thread(target=feed, args=(q_in,)))
    threads.append(Thread(target=dispatch, args=(q_in, qs_out)))
    
    for q_out in qs_out:
        threads.append(Thread(target=worker, args=(q_out,)))

    for t in threads: t.start() 
    for t in threads: t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this code, `worker` is a consumer and `feed` the unique producer. Three consumers threads and the producer threads are executed concurrently. The `dispatch` worker is responsible for duplicating the input and feeding the multiple consumers.